# LINQ DefaultIfEmpty should return array of object with null value

Tags: vb.net, linq, defaultifempty

I have this LINQ query:

```
Dim JoinedResult = LeftTable.GroupJoin(RightTable, Function(LeftTableRow) LeftTableRow(FieldIndexInLeftTable), _
                                     Function(RightTableRow) RightTableRow(FieldIndexInRightTable), _
                                     Function(LeftTableRow, RightTableRow) _
                                     New With {LeftTableRow, RightTableRow}).SelectMany(Function(Rows) Rows.RightTableRow.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(Function(Right) New With {Rows.LeftTableRow, Right}))
```

`LeftTable` has 5 columns, `RightTable` has 2 columns.

There is a match only in case of the first 11 rows:

[image]

The question is, how should I modify the `DefaultIfEmpty()`, that I get an object array with two elements, where each element is let's say nothing (the main point is, the elements should be null).

I should do it in the way, that the column number of `RightTable` can be changing.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have the solution.

I create an object array with 2 elements:

```
Dim NullValue() As Object = Nothing
Array.Resize(NullValue, 2)
NullValue(0) = DBNull.Value
NullValue(1) = DBNull.Value
```

and then I use it in the `DefaultIfEmpty()` function like this: `DefaultIfEmpty(NullValue)`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as "answer"